# How can i change url name?

Tags: web, shiny, shiny-server

I have a web url that look like: http://122.213.174.190:3838/.

How can i change this name url to something else?

Just for the appearance.

Comment: To what do you want to change it? And you can't change a hostname "just for appearance". Either it's a hostname that resolves and works or it's not. There's no "appearance" layer on top of some underlying actual protocol layer.

Comment: I want to change it to something www.MoreInformativeName.com.  my hostname is working.

Comment: Then you need to register the domain www.moreinformativename.com and set up your DNS appropriately.

Comment: That depends on where you buy the domain name and where your server may be hosted.

Comment: Does it mean that i need to put all my documents and data-bases to another server?

Comment: No. It means you need to purchase that domain name at a domain name registrar, then set up the DNS records for the domain so it points at your server, and then possibly tell your server that it's supposed to serve pages for that domain.